# How to create a flow chart using mermaid that where children should be seperate for each parent, though it is same children

Tags: mermaid

**Expected flowchart to be:**

[image]

With below code, i could see the children getting clubbed togethere since the children is same. Is it possible to have different children for each parent, though the children are same ?

```
flowchart TB
    access-denied --> content-viewport --> yield
    404 --> content-viewport --> yield
    feature-not-available --> content-viewport --> feature-not-available-component
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - this is not currently possible. However, if you give each "content-viewport" a unique ID you can achieve something similar:

flowchart TB
access-denied --> content-viewport1[content-viewport] --> yield1[yield]
404 --> content-viewport2[content-viewport] --> yield2[yield]
feature-not-available --> content-viewport3[content-viewport] --> feature-not-available-component

https://mermaid.live/edit#pako:eNp9kU1PwzAMhv9KlfOyrh90Ww8cEBw5wYl1Bzdx24g0qVK30zT1v5N2AgQa5JL49esnsXNhwkpkOau0PYkGHAWvD4UJ_AIhsO-5RKNQBpzfB8IaQkN8VHjqrKPo8Fs5Lr6zQi2jw7Idr7B0k95ExP8h4h-ICoEGh9xY4jCC0lBqvAlN_oDeJHBh284a72Yr1qJrQUk_j8t8acGowRYLlvujBPdesMJM3gcD2ZezESwnN-CKDZ0EwkcFtYOW5RXo3qsdmDdrv2OUiqx7vg58mftn5dOS-TJqCxJ9eGF07mZzrfr5eb6tStWzPjjt5Yao6_MwnNPrWlEzlGvfTtgrOX9lM-6zMIuzHcQJZtsE7pJEijLa76o4jSq53UQxsGmaPgDTWLHg